# Special Characters in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am building an application in VS C# using a My SQL database. However, it crashed every time I try to read values with special characters from the database. My schema collation is utf8-default collation. I am not sure what to do next, can anyone assist?

Error: "Error in SQL syntax, check manual that corresponds to your mySQL server version"

code:

```
string query = "select description from tableName where description = '"+codeName+"' ";
string codevalue = Browse.selectUsingReader(query);
```

I am trying to get the line "Out of range of women's reproductive age." stored in my database to be displayed to the user. The apostrophe is what is throwing the exception because if I delete it, I get no errors.

Further when trying to store special characters like "# @" for passwords I having a similar problem.

Comment: what special characters? post some example test data and the code you use to pull the values from the db.

Comment: Please post more specific information.

Comment: Please post 1) examples, 2) output, 3) code.

Comment: mainly **'(apostrophe char is affects the database)**
please put ' with his &#39; in database

Comment: softsdev is wrong. Don't do that. Just escape it to \'.

Comment: If i use \ then that also appears in my display.